# htaccess hide folder name from url in both directions

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want my urls to look nice.
So when I have this url:

> localhost/pages

I want the url to look like this:

> localhost/

I already solved, that when I type in localhost/pages I get the index file from /pages, but when I type in /pages it is still showing:

> localhost/pages.

How can I change, that /pages is not shown?

My htaccess code:
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current rewrite rule redirects `localhost/foo` to `localhost/pages/foo` and it serves `localhost/pages/foo`. Change your rewrite rule to:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)$ $1 [L]
```